# How to create a canvas inside JFrame and draw a few basic shapes?

Tags: java, swing

I am new to java and created my own window frame. Now i just need to draw few graphics shapes into it.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class run {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

int resx = 400,resy = 400;

frame.setSize(resx,resy);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setTitle("Mover");
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}
}
```

Comment: You can take a look of this link http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find more about paint [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html).

A simple example is below.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SimpleDrawing extends JFrame {

public SimpleDrawing() {

    setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(20, 50, 100, 100);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 200);
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new SimpleDrawing();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Go through the paint method in the code.

Comment: Don't override paint of top level containers, apart form Anyang else, they are not double buffered, on window based top,level containers, this will allow you to paint underneath frame borders. You should always call super.paintXxx to ensure that the paint requirements of the paint chain are maintained. There is no need to extend from JFrame, yu are not adding any funtnalty to the class

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could start with [2D Graphcs Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

I'd also use a `JComponent` or `JPanel` instead of `Canvas`